# How to make Search Dialog size of a toolbar

Tags: android, search, layout, toolbar, search-dialog

So I learned how to make Search dialog with [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) but it doesn't look pretty and I'm looking for proper way to fix it. As you can see search widget doesn't cover fully the toolbar and I think making it shorter by using constant `dp` values is not a good way(isn't it?). Second thing is I'm not quite sure why half of toolbar is white and half of it is blue?

[image: before]
[image: after pressing magnifier button]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFF"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#2196F3"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Styles:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to Shujito answer and [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) I made it work. Here is the modified code if someone was interested:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // retrieve the searchview here
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `SearchView` instead of a Search dialog, it is more flexible and it can be easily embedded into a xml menu, and it will fit the height of the action bar, try this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/desc_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
</menu>
```

Inflate this into your activity or fragment, here's an example for a fragment. Then you can retrieve the `SearchView` with the item's `getActionView()` method

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.workload, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    // retrieve the searchview here
    this.mSearchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
}
```

Comment: this is almost great! however when I try to request search nothing happens. SearchableActivity doesn't open ??

Comment: unless you specifically need a searchable interface, you can try using a ´OnQueryTextListener´ on the searchview and capture the query on the receiving method, there are other listeners, check the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html
also, I prefer using searchviews because they are more flexible than search interfaces, they don't have as much outside integration as a search interface, but because I don't need outside access it works for me.

Comment: Thanks! I made it work by looking to documentation again(see my edit). Somehow I missed your solution when reading documentation. There was suggestion to use search widget instead dialog if you have already `toolbar` or `actionbar` in your layout but I was sure that I will need some extra work.